# Is "a current" ever grammatical?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

As I understand it, the indefinite article "a" cannot be used before the word "current". "A current ..." doesn't make sense to me. We say "the next" and "the previous", so we should say "the current", that's it.

> Regardless of which info category is selected on the Status bar menu, at any time you can click and hold on the Status bar to learn the dimensions, number of channels, color mode, bit depth, and resolution of **the current document**.
>
> Photoshop CC: Visual QuickStart Guide

But nevertheless it is used in this way sometimes. Is it grammatical? If yes, then how it works?

> Expired or superseded documents. The only exception to this are Academic Regulations, where versions from previous years are still available via Governance Zone. In all other cases, to consult a previous version of **a current document** or an expired document, please contact us.
>
> https://www.kcl.ac.uk/governancezone/about

> If you are lodging directly with us, each applicant and their spouse/partner must provide a copy (not the original) of **a current document** from each of the four categories (i.e. four documents per person). A single document cannot be used for more than one category.
>
> https://www.sro.vic.gov.au/fhogapply

Comment: Who told you that? Of course, a current document. Why wouldn't it be grammatical? current is an adjective. Adjectives are not what controls an article.

Comment: @Lambie But if you ask me which books are my favorite, and I answer you something like "It's hard to say. The previous book I have read was ..., the next book I'm going to read is ..., and the book which I read now (= these days) is ...", it should be "the" in all the three cases, right?

Comment: If you only ever read one book at a time, then there will only be one current book.  If you're reading more than one book, you can say, "A book that I'm currently reading is *War and Peace.*"  We wouldn't call this "a current book" - but not because it's ungrammatical.  We just don't use usually use *current* in this collocation.  The following is pretty idiomatic, though: "I love a lot of books.  **A current favorite** of mine is *War and Peace*."

Comment: Also, "current" has more than one meaning. In computing, a "current document" means one that's open now (currently). There can be more than one document open at a time, so there can be more than one "current document". In terms of demonstrating proof of ID or qualifications, "current" means "in effect", as in, "has taken effect and has not expired". Two of the current documents I have are a driver's licence and a passport.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is more than one document current in a particular context, meaning, for example, that there are documents that have not expired, you can certainly refer to any one of them  as "a current document".

You can even use it in a general sense:

> A *current documen*t will have a date in the upper right hand corner that is not earlier than today's date.

In short, the usual rules for selecting articles apply, and are not affected by the choice of adjective.

Comment: If there is more than one document current....